# Android Studio 3.6 applies changes only on the second Run

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, libgdx

After update AS to 3.6 IDE applies changes only when I run it twice. Why that could be? I make games using Libgdx in AS. When I run standart android projects it works fine (applies changes on the first Run).

Comment: The only way to apply changes at first run for now is to make core module first and then run, but it is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate it too, this happens because auto save has been disabled I can't find much info on this on internet, my solution is to save (Ctrl + S) before running every time.
Also the second time you run maybe the default 15 seconds for the new automatic save had passed, you can find it under the editor settings.

Comment: Didn't know it happens because autosave disabled, thank you (hitting Ctrl+S is much faster than make module all the time as I did).

Comment: If you find how to enable it like it was before please share here, the best I could do is set the auto save after 1 second of inactivity, still having me pressing Ctrl + S because 1 second is still too much